# Can't boot without 'nolapic' kernel option. And system hangs after few minutes

Tags: 11.04, boot, hardware

The title describes my problem. Also with 'lapic' option, only one core is enabled.

Tried with 10.10(amd64), 11.04(amd64)

10.10 x86 version didn't boot with nolapic option. Now I'm using 11.04 amd64 version (updated).

/proc/cpuinfo :

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 4
model name  : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
stepping    : 3
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
bogomips    : 6495.17
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate
```

My new computer's spec is, (sadly :( )
AMD Phenom II 955
ASRock 770iCafe
GV-R577SL-1GD (GIGABYTE 5770 VGA)

output of lshw command :

```
mattengi-desktop
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 770iCafe
       vendor: ASRock
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P1.50
          date: 09/07/2010
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPUSocket
          size: 3200MHz
          capacity: 3200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 11
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: PartNum0
             vendor: Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum0
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: PartNum1
             vendor: Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum1
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: [empty]
             product: PartNum2
             vendor: Manufacturer2
             physical id: 2
             serial: SerNum2
             slot: DIMM2
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             product: PartNum3
             vendor: Manufacturer3
             physical id: 3
             serial: SerNum3
             slot: DIMM3
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: RX780/RX790 Chipset Host Bridge
          vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          resources: memory:0-1fffffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:10 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:feb00000-febfffff ioport:d0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Juniper [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:10 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:febe0000-febfffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:febc0000-febdffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
                resources: irq:11 memory:febbc000-febbffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port F)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:10 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fea00000-feafffff ioport:cff00000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:25:22:5a:f8:78
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:10 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:cffff000-cfffffff memory:cffe0000-cffeffff memory:feaf0000-feafffff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
             resources: irq:11 ioport:c000(size=8) ioport:b000(size=4) ioport:a000(size=8) ioport:9000(size=4) ioport:8000(size=16) memory:fe9ff800-fe9ffbff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: OCZ-VERTEX2
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 1.32
                serial: OCZ-SGVCNP7YX4N4SEP7
                size: 55GiB (60GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000df786
              *-volume:0
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 726dc46e-de39-4fd4-b7c1-9aba13d54e2d
                   size: 51GiB
                   capacity: 51GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-04-16 07:13:02 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2011-04-16 07:16:44 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2011-04-16 07:44:24 state=mounted
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 4094MiB
                   capacity: 4094MiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 4094MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:7 memory:fe9fe000-fe9fefff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 12.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:7 memory:fe9fd000-fe9fdfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:10 memory:fe9ff000-fe9ff0ff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:10 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fcfff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:10 memory:fe9fb000-fe9fbfff
        *-usb:5
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:11 memory:fe9fa800-fe9fa8ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 3c
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ht cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=64
             resources: irq:7 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ff00(size=16)
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=32
             resources: irq:7 memory:fe9f4000-fe9f7fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
        *-usb:6
             description: USB Controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
             vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:10 memory:fe9f9000-fe9f9fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Address Map
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 10h Processor Link Control
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Changed M/B for same model. All works fine.

Comment: Congratulation on resolving your own question.  To be helpful to others who may experience the same issue in future, can you accept your answer, and if possible provide more details how you came to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is most probably a kernel issue.  However to diagnose is difficult through askubuntu - a better forum based arena would I'm sure provide a more interactive question and answer type scenario to find an answer.  My advice is therefore more generic.
2. Since you have tried lapic as a boot option, what other options have you tried?  This link has some commonly used boot options that you may/may not have tried.[enter link description here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)
3. Sometimes looking on your motherboard website there could be an updated bios update you could try.
4. Some people have perversely found that the 32bit ubuntu is better on a 64bit CPU and visa-versa.
5. Have a look in your BIOS options.  Sometimes, for whatever reason, ACPI is disabled.  If you have this option (or something like "power management") make sure it is enabled.